# Ramda - how to get nested array values

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am trying to get values from nested arrays using Ramda. I have multiple groups like in the example below. I need to get all children from all `sections` and all `childrenWithoutSections` in one array of strings.

```js
const groups = [
   {
      "id":"10",
      "sections":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "children":["10", "11"]
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "children":["12"]
         }
      ],
      "childrenWithoutSections":["1", "2"]
   },
   {
      "id":"11",
      "sections":[
         {
            "id":"3",
            "children":["13", "14"]
         },
         {
            "id":"4",
            "children":["15"]
         }
      ],
      "childrenWithoutSections":["3", "4"]
   }
]
```

I started with something like this:

```js
R.pipe(
  R.pluck(['childrenWithoutSections']),
  R.flatten
)(groups)
```

And as a result, I got all the children from one required key but I have no idea how to get nested values from `sections/children`?

Comment: Anything wrong with simply doing `groups .flatMap (g => [... g .sections .flatMap (s => s.children), ... g . childrenWithoutSections])` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to support IE11 :/ Probably I can find some polyfills to use it there but using Ramda is easier.

Comment: This is similar: `R .chain (g => R .chain (s => s.children, g .sections) .concat (g . childrenWithoutSections), groups)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the suggestions in the comments, we can also write a point-free version of this:

```js
const extract = chain (
  lift (concat) (
    pipe (prop ('sections'), pluck ('children'), flatten), 
    prop ('childrenWithoutSections')
  )
)

const groups = [{id: "10", sections: [{id: "1", children: ["10", "11"]}, {id: "2", children: ["12"]}], childrenWithoutSections: ["1", "2"]}, {id: "11", sections: [{id: "3", children: ["13", "14"]}, {id: "4", children: ["15"]}], childrenWithoutSections: ["3", "4"]}]

console .log (extract (groups))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.2/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {chain, lift, concat, pipe, prop, pluck, flatten} = R     </script>
```

Comment: As always exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `R.juxt` to get `children` from the `sections`, and the `childrenWithoutSections` and then flattening the results. By chaining the results we get the array of values.

```js
const {chain, pipe, juxt, prop, pluck, flatten } = R 

const fn = chain(pipe(
  juxt([
    pipe(prop('sections'), pluck('children')),
    prop('childrenWithoutSections')
  ]),
  flatten,
))

const groups = [{id: "10", sections: [{id: "1", children: ["10", "11"]}, {id: "2", children: ["12"]}], childrenWithoutSections: ["1", "2"]}, {id: "11", sections: [{id: "3", children: ["13", "14"]}, {id: "4", children: ["15"]}], childrenWithoutSections: ["3", "4"]}]

const result = fn(groups)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.2/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice!  There's so often more than one good way to do these things.

Comment: I must say you two always have great ways to do `these things`... So thank you both :)